# GnuTLS verify certificate: anything easy to use?

Tags: gnutls

In OpenSSL, I can verify certificate using the following command.

```
$ openssl verify -CApath /etc/ssl/certs cert_to_be_verified.pem
```

I wonder if there is similar command in GnuTLS. The closest one I can find is "certtool". But "certtool" needs to specify the CA file, which is kind of very inconvenient compared with OpenSSL. Thanks a lot for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually certtool does not require you to specify the CA file. It will use your system's certificate list instead.

From the [certtool documentation](https://www.gnutls.org/manual/html_node/certtool-Invocation.html):

> The trusted certificate list can be loaded with --load-ca-certificate. If no certificate list is provided, then the system's certificate list is used. Note that during verification multiple paths may be explored. On
>                 a successful verification the successful path will be the last one. It can be combined with --verify-purpose or --verify-hostname.

```
$ certtool --verify --infile google.com.crt
Loaded system trust (168 CAs available)
Loaded 3 certificates, 168 CAs and 0 CRLs

    Subject: CN=GeoTrust Global CA,O=GeoTrust Inc.,C=US
    Issuer: OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority,O=Equifax,C=US
    Checked against: OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority,O=Equifax,C=US
    Output: Verified. The certificate is trusted.

    Subject: CN=Google Internet Authority G2,O=Google Inc,C=US
    Issuer: CN=GeoTrust Global CA,O=GeoTrust Inc.,C=US
    Checked against: CN=GeoTrust Global CA,O=GeoTrust Inc.,C=US
    Output: Verified. The certificate is trusted.

    Subject: CN=*.google.com,O=Google Inc,L=Mountain View,ST=California,C=US
    Issuer: CN=Google Internet Authority G2,O=Google Inc,C=US
    Checked against: CN=Google Internet Authority G2,O=Google Inc,C=US
    Output: Verified. The certificate is trusted.

Chain verification output: Verified. The certificate is trusted.
```